# Solving for $(x,y): 2+\frac1{x+\frac1{y+\frac15}}=\frac{478}{221}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, problem-solving

Solving for $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$:

$$2+\dfrac1{x+\dfrac1{y+\dfrac15}}=\frac{478}{221}$$

This doesn't make any sense; I made $y+\frac15=\frac{5y+1}5$, and so on, but it turns out to be a very complicated fraction on the left hand side, and I don't even know if what I got is correct.

Is there a more mathematical way to approach this problem?

Comment: See [continued fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a very large and important mathematical theory, called the theory of [*Continued Fractions*.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) These have many uses, both in number theory and in analysis (approximation of functions).

Let's go backwards.

The number $\frac{478}{221}$ is $2+\frac{36}{221}$, which is $2+\frac{1}{\frac{221}{36}}$.

But $\frac{221}{36}=6+\frac{5}{36}$, which is $6+\frac{1}{\frac{36}{5}}$.

Finally, $\frac{36}{5}=7+\frac{1}{5}$.

Now compare the results of these calculations with your expression.

Comment: This does show that $x=6$ and $y=7$ satisfy the given equation, but how would you prove that these are the only solutions (assuming that this is the case)?

Comment: @Alraxite: Good question! I had decided to not mention that issue. For rationals, there is a theorem that the simple continued fraction expansion is essentially unique, By essentially unique I mean that (in this case) there is also a one level deeper continued fraction, obtained by replacing $5$ by $1+4$. (Irrationals have an absolutely unique continued fraction expansion.) The proof of uniqueness is short, it is in every introduction to continued fractions.

Answer (score 5):

Let's see,
$$\frac{478}{221}=2+\frac{36}{221}=2+\dfrac1{\frac{221}{36}}=2+\frac1{6+\frac5{36}}=2+\dfrac1{6+\dfrac1{\frac{36}{5}}}=2+\dfrac1{6+\dfrac1{7+\frac15}}$$

Thus, $x=6,y=7$.

Answer (score -1):

To see uniqueness,

we look at Danny's solution.

Let's see,
\begin{align}
\frac{478}{221}&=2+\frac{36}{221} &\text{2 is the only integer which will make the leftover fraction less than 1}\\
&=2+\dfrac1{\frac{221}{36}}\\&
=2+\frac1{6+\frac5{36}} &\text{Here, 6 is the only number which will make the left over fraction positive and less than 1}\\
&=2+\dfrac1{6+\dfrac1{\frac{36}{5}}}\\
&=2+\dfrac1{6+\dfrac1{7+\frac15}} &\text{and here, 7 is the only number}
\end{align}

Thus, $x=6,y=7$.